# Spring Data Projection with OneToMany error

Tags: spring, jpa, one-to-many, projection

I have a entity call Circuit.

```
@Entity
public class Circuit implements Comparable<Circuit>, Serializable {
@Column
  private String id;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "circuit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Step> workflow = new HashSet<>();
...

}
```

I have a class called CircuitLight

```
public class CircuitLight {

    private String id;
    private Set<Step> workflow;

/* constructor, getters and setters */

}
```

In my CircuitRepository, i'm trying to make a projection

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Query("select new com.docapost.circuit.CircuitLight(c.id, c.workflow) from Circuit c where c.account.siren = :siren")
    Set<CircuitLight> findAllByAccountSirenProjection(@Param("siren") String siren);
```

When i execute, i have a error message:
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'circuit0_.id' in 'on clause'

I try with other entity. Every time i have a property with a relation @OneToMany, i have the issue...
Is it possible to make a projection with class (Without use a interface) when there are a relation OneToMany ?

**UPDATE**:
Step.class

```
@Entity
public class Step implements Comparable<Step>, Serializable {

  private static final List<String> INDEXABLE_PROCESSES = Arrays.asList(
    ParapheurWorkflowModel.SERVER,
    ParapheurWorkflowModel.SIGN,
    ParapheurWorkflowModel.VISA
  );

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Expose
  @SerializedName("step_id")
  public long id;

  @ManyToOne
  public Circuit circuit;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "step_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "technicalGroup_id"))
  private List<TechnicalGroup> technicalGroups = new ArrayList<>();

  @Column(name = "step_type", nullable = false)
  @Expose
  @SerializedName("subprocess_ref")
  public String type;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  public int orderIndex;


 /* contructor, getters and setters */
 
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:
Hum.... My bad, in my circuit class, i have a EmbeddedId

```
 @EmbeddedId
  private CircuitPK key;

@Embeddable
  public static class CircuitPK implements Serializable {
    public String id;
    public String siren;
}
```

I try with this code in Step.class

```
 @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumns(value = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "circuit_siren", referencedColumnName = "siren"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "circuit_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  })
  public Circuit circuit;
```

The result is the same

Comment: Can you post your `Step` class?

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in the Step entity

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
private Circuit circuit;
```